# Query to fetch intersection in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a 2 tables - `rout` and `loc`.

Table Rout Columns:

```
Id (PK)
file_key
rout_no
....
```

This table has 800k records

Table Loc Columns

```
catalog_no(PK)
country_id    
...
```

This table has 700k records. So I want something like this (Intersection of between two tables)

```
SELECT rout.file_key,rout.rout_no,loc.country_id  
FROM ROUT_TBL rout, LOC_TBL loc 
WHERE rout.file_key != loc.catalog_no
```

Can you tell me how?

Comment: intersect is a set operation.  See here for more: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking.  "Intersection" is a mathematical term that indicates that you want to determine which values exist in both tables.  But the query you posted appears to be looking for the exact opposite-- the set of rows in one table that don't exist in the other.

If you really mean intersection

```
SELECT rout.file_key,
       rout.rout_no,
       loc.country_id
  FROM rout_tbl rout 
       JOIN loc_tbl loc ON (rout.file_key = loc.catalog_no)
```

If you want all the rows in `ROUT` that don't exist in `LOC`

```
SELECT rout.file_key,
       rout.rout_no
  FROM rout_tbl rout
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                     FROM loc_tbl loc
                    WHERE loc.catalog_no = rout.file_key )
```

If you want the data from `ROUT` along with the data from `LOC` if it exists

```
SELECT rout.file_key,
       rout.rout_no,
       loc.country_id
  FROM rout_tbl rout 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN loc_tbl loc ON (rout.file_key = loc.catalog_no)
```